# Testing errors and promises with jasmine

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, jasmine

Testing errors and promises. I have a situation similar to the one below:

```
public myUtilityMethod(): Promise<string> {
  // some synchronous stuff
  console.log('bla bla');
  // some asynchronous stuff
  return Promise.resolve('ok');
}
public async doSomething(): Promise<void> {
  let promise;
  try {
    promise = this.myUtilityMethod();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new MyError('I knew it', e, {});
  }
  await Promise.all([promise]);
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

I want to test, when something goes wrong in the synchronous part of myUtilityMethod, I throw a MyError, so I write the following test

```
it('should throw MyError when something goes wrong in the synchronous part of myUtilityMethod', fakeAsync(() => {
  // given
  const error = new Error('something went wrong');
  component.myUtilityMethod = sinon.stub().throws(error);
  // when
 expect(() => {
   component.doSomething();
   flushMicrotasks();
 }).toThrow(jasmine.any(MyError));
}));
```

The test fails because

```
        Error: Expected function to throw <jasmine.any(MyError)>, but it threw Error: Uncaught (in promise): MyError: {"message":"i knew it","nativeError":{},"context":{}}.
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions wrap all their content in a promise, so even if the error is thrown before any "await" is encountered, what happens is that the promise rejects instead of throwing an error. The following test passes:

```
  it('test test', (done) => {
    const error = new Error('something went wrong');
    component.myUtilityMethod = sinon.stub().throws(error);

    component.doSomething().catch((e) => {
      expect(e).toEqual(jasmine.any(MyError));
      done();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your assertion is not correct. You're mocking that `doSomething` to throw `new Error('something went wrong')` but you're expecting a `MyError`.

I would stub `myUtilityMethod` to throw the `Error` so then it goes in your `catch` block and the `throw new MyError('I knew it', e, {})` to be traversed.

```
it('should throw MyError when something goes wrong in the synchronous part of myUtilityMethod', fakeAsync(() => {
  // given
  const error = new Error('something went wrong');
  component.myUtilityMethod = sinon.stub().throws(error); // make myUtilityMethod throw the error
  // when
 expect(() => {
   component.doSomething(); // once myUtilityMethod throws the error, doSomething's catch block will run
   flushMicrotasks();
 }).toThrow(new LabelGenerationError('I knew it', error, {}));
}));
```

Edit: After looking at your new error:

```
// change this line to back to how it was
.toThrow(jasmine.any(MyError));
// to this
.toThrow(new LabelGenerationError('I knew it', error, {}));
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I did a mistake in writing the question. Yet, it still stands.

Comment: Check out your error and see `expected` vs. `actual`. Check out my edit. I am thinking that's it.

Comment: I found what's the issue was actually. An `async` function wraps all its content in a promise. So to test what I'm trying to, I need to use promise.catch.